# Orbeon forms drop down menu performance issues

Tags: orbeon

We have an application that is running on orbeon forms. When a new form is created there are dropdown options to select. The second drop down option is populated based on the first drop down option when we try to select the option from the drop down the values on the second drop down takes a long time about 5 minutes to load. In the logs the below error is found

ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
XFormsServer  - Ajax update lock timeout exceeded, returning error to client

The attached image shows the drop down 1 the option is selected but the second drop down loads after a delay of 5 minutes

[image: DropdownMenuLoading issue]

Attached is the error we are getting in the inspect -> Network tab of browser

[image: NetworkTabError]

Any ideas on this issue. We are using orbeon-2016.2.201608230055-CE version let me know if additional details required.

Comment: Shriram, I am wondering why the second dropdown takes 5 minutes to load. Are you using a Dynamic Dropdown? If so, is the service you are calling fast, or is that service taking multiple minutes to answer?

Comment: Hi Shriram, have you figured out what the problem was? If not, does it look like your service takes quite a bit of time to respond (also see my previous message). ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Avernet Apologies for delayed response. we are using dynamic drop downs. The second drop down is dependent on the first drop down.  We still get ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Received request XFormsServer - Ajax update lock timeout exceeded, returning error to client

Comment: could not find the root cause though further investigating

Comment: Got it Shriram, I known this might be difficult because you're calling services, but would you by any chance be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that we can run here, and include a link to it in a response so we can look into it? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Avernet  I'm getting the below warning also "XFormsServer  - xxf:instance() - instance not found {instance id: "fr-xforms-inspector-input"}"

Comment: Hi Shriram, this is used by XForms Inspector. Do you have the `oxf.epilogue.xforms.inspector` property set to `true` in your `properties-local.xml`? If so, you can try setting it to `false`.You'll let me know if this helps. ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Avernet Thanks for the update I have set it to false and dont have this warning anymore however the drop down takes a long time to load not sure of this issue. We are having multiple forms in the same Orbeon set up and only one specific form gives this performance problem. Do you have any other method where we can trace this issue. Now there are no errors shown on the logs but the drop down takes a long time to load.

Comment: Hi Shriram, I think having a look at the `orbeon.log` might help. So we have more information in the log, could you please try to set your logging as described in the [Development configuration section](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/xforms-logging.html) of the XForms Logging page, stop your server, remove the `orbeon.log`, restart the server, reproduce the issue, put the `orbeon.log` you get somewhere, and put a link to the location in a comment? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Shriram, if this issue still is on your front-burner, did you get a chance to try collecting the `orbeon.log`, as mentioned in my previous message? ‑Alex